# What architecture should it be my .a for running on iOS Device and iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, x86-64

I have build a fat library with the architectures "arm64", "armv7" and "x86" from various lib.a. I have no problem when I compile the project for iOS Devices but it seems the compilation goes wrong when I try it into a iOS simulator. It says "Undefined Symbols for x86_64". I can Imagine that I need also the x86_64 lib.a But I wonder what can I do for solving the problem.

Note: 
The libraries where manually compiled from [OpenHome](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet)

Than you

Edited:
Could be because of the makefile from [Here](https://github.com/openhome/ohNet/blob/master/Makefile)

Comment: You've answered to your own q. You need x86 to work w/ simulator.

Comment: but i thought x86 (I have already) was the one...

Comment: Then try to make only x86/64 for test and see how it works. You should then see err w/ arm.

Comment: I see. I have followed the instructions from the link provided. Do you think the Makefile contains and option for that? Sorry but all that gets a little bit confusing...

Comment: put a bit more as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a first step, make sure if your fat bin definitely includes x86_64.
To do so, you can check w/ cmd as follows.

```
$ xcrun lipo -info yourLibrary.a
```

If your lib definitely contains x86_64, it should show

```
Architectures in the fat file: yourLibrary.a are: x86_64 arm64 ...
```

For example, I have compiled libpng for x86_64 and arm64 for my app. The xcrun command shows as follow.

```
$ xcrun lipo -info libpng.a
  Architectures in the fat file: libpng.a are: x86_64 arm64
```

Needless to say, fat bin has both arm64 and x86 (since it's FAT). So fat bin doesn't require separate x86_64 lib.a as you mentioned in you q.

Checking your Makefile is after you confirmed your fat bin has x86_64.

Comment: Clearly is not in x86_64. it says "Architectures in the fat file: lib.a are: armv7 i386 arm64". But it is weird because the lib compressed files says "x86"...

Comment: I have accepted your answer as correct because you said something that made realise There is another option for compiling for iOS x86. Can you please say if iOS x86 stands for the simulator for 64 bits computers and i386 for simulator for 32 bits computer?

Comment: Not quite sure w/ simulator. But when I typed "uname -a" in terminal, it says "Darwin ...... i386" for my 32bit mac, and "Darwin ...... x86_64" for my 64bit mac. So I believe i386 is for 32bit. You can check w/ you PC.

Comment: I saw a bit the Makefile; at line-50, it checks if $(iOs-x64) is 1, which seems what you need. Please check it.

Comment: yes that is the bit I realised after reading your answer. Thank you very much.